# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' How to solve this however I have all Mysql work bench and connectors

Tags: python, mysql

I have this problem when I try to connect mysql to python, I tried Git and Python IDLE, it was not working however I have donloaded all Mysql python connection packages from pip and python too, but still any command will come out like (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql') that is the outcome, appreciate your recommentdations!

GIT
PYTHON
Pycharm
Mysql installlers
Python connectors all

Comment: Please review the spelling of your question to make it clearer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what code you put in the python IDLE.

If you put `from module import *`, then you dont need to do `module.thing()`, you can just do `thing()`.

Some modules require you using it in the terminal.

For more information, visit https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/